# Reading Xmls from folders and parsing

Tags: python, xml, pandas

I have two problems

first problem: I got some XMLs with different names in a folder, and I want to read them and only parse what have a specific number in its name 
as an example

```
XMLs filenames: 1234_ashe_info.xml , 2345_none_info.xml
```

if the file contains 1234 in its name, then I need to parse it so what can I do to read all files from the folder and then do that map?

second problem: I got a DataFrame with some info, I need to search if that info is in my XML, as an example:

```
names   age
Ashe    12
John    14
Karin   23
```

I need to search for name if it's found in the XML and if yes to check that age is equal or no

the schema of the XML is :

```
<Value id="1234556">
<Type>NAME</Type>
<Description>Ashe</Description>
<age>12</age>
</Value>
```

what can i do ?
my language is python

Comment: Please ask about one problem at a time. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You need first to iterate the files in the folder, parse the xml data and finally check your condition:

```
import os
import xmltodict


for file in os.listdir(dir):

    #if file meets your condition
    if (file.startswith('1234')):

        with open(file, 'rb') as f:
            data = xmltodict.parse(f)

        #check if it is in the dataframe
        if (df['name']==data['Type']) & (df['age']==data['age'])).any():
            #do what you want here
```